# Print if the array is overflowing or not

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have this array which would store the result of the addition of two arrays. The size of this array is `10` and the size of the arrays of the numbers to be added is also `10`

**My question is** I want to print `"Overflow"` if the array overflows after the addition and print `"No change"` if number of elements in array, after addition, does not exceed `10`.

I am trying to implement 2 cases:

i. First is to increase the size of the '**`result`**' array to 11 and then give the condition

```
if (result[11]!=int(32))
    cout<<"Overflow"<<endl;
```

ii. The other logic I am trying to use is:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i=0;i<11;++i){
    if (result[i]!= int(16))
       ++count;
}

cout<<count<<endl;

if (count >10)
    cout<<"Overflow"<<endl;
```

Problem is, it is printing the **`count`** as `11` even if the result consists of `10` numbers in the array.

I am also thinking of using dynamic arrays, but I am new to C++, so do not know if that would be a good idea. I would appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: So, are you basically trying to add bounds checking to a primitive array?

Comment: Yes that would be one way to say it.

Comment: Since you're using C++, prefer to use `std::array` or `std::vector`.  The `at()` member function provides runtime bounds checking, while `std::get` provides compiletime bounds checking. Otherwise, consider using a static analysis tool or clang and gcc's `-fsanitize=undefined`. GCC may also catch out of bounds access via a warning.

Comment: @nothing since primitive arrays have no bounds checking, you can't do this. You have to keep track of the number of elements explicitly for yourself. But why don't you just use `std::vector` instead?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant How I would be able to do that? Changing the array type to vector?

Comment: @nothing In first place, yes. And then you don't have to do anything else -- use the `at` member function on the vector and you get instant bounds checking for free.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is create a buffer region outside the array to catch extra writes:

```
int array[SIZE + 1];
array[SIZE] = MAGIC;

// use array [0... SIZE-1]

if (array[SIZE] != MAGIC) /* overflowed */
```

However, while this catches overruns up to the size of the buffer region, if the code goes past that, you have undefined behavior, and your `if` test at the end is not guaranteed to work properly after UB happens.  There's also a slight chance of the actual value being written being equal to `MAGIC`... but the chances of that happening are pretty small if you choose the canary value properly.

It's a pretty good start for overrun detection, though, and most dynamic allocators do something like this in debug compiles.

A more advanced technique is to place the array right next to an invalid region of memory, in which case the CPU hardware (the memory protection unit, to be exact) will generate a trap (access violation or SIGSEGV) at the exact location of the out-of-bounds access.  The `efence` library uses this technique.

Comment: would it be possible to elaborate it a little ?

Comment: @nothing: Which part did you have questions about?

Comment: I have already increased the size of the result array from '10' to '11' so why there is a need to use a buffer?

Comment: @nothing: You increased the size to 11 and then used the 12th element.  That's no good.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is, it is printing the count as '11' even if the result
>   consists of 10 numbers in the array.

This is because your loop is running 11 times as well as incrementing count 11 times i.e from 0 to 10.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
```

Comment: The increment of count is not unconditional.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is, it is printing the count as '11' even if the result
>   consists of 10 numbers in the array.

If I understand this correctly, you're accessing the 10th index of an array of size 10 which is undefined behavior because it's out of bounds access.

If you're using C++03, you can avoid the usage of raw arrays and prefer `std::vector`. `std::vector` automatically handles memory for you and its `at()` member function will throw an exception if you try provide an out of bounds index. Be warned that `operator[]` does not provide bounds checking.

In C++11, you can use `std::array`. Similar to `std::vector`, it has `at()` which provides bounds checking and `operator[]` which does not. The non-member function `std::get` provides compile-time bounds checking. Here is an example:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::get<6>(arr);
// error: static assertion failed: index is out of bounds
arr.at(6);
// terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
//   what():  array::at: __n (which is 6) >= _Nm (which is 5)
```

If you're stuck with raw arrays, your compiler may come with diagnostics or tools that help catch out of bounds errors, such as LLVM's undefined behavior sanitizer (which has been ported to GCC) and Valgrind (which reports memory errors.) Here's an example of Clang giving an out of bounds warning:

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
arr[6];
// warning: array index 6 is past the end of the array (which contains 5 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
```

And the message you get if you run it with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`:

```
runtime error: index 6 out of bounds for type 'int [5]'
```

GCC catching undefined behavior in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[i];
// warning: iteration 5u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
```

This is a good argument to use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, which work for both compilers, although be warned that the exact diagnostics you get vary, so always test your code with multiple tools.

Answer (score -1):

> > *"My question is i want to print "Overflow" if the array overflows after the addition and print "No change" if number of elements in array, after addition, do not exceed 10."*

You have to do out of bounds index checks prior access, or use an out of bounds checker code injections beforehand.

Comment: You can also make the storage larger than necessary for the array, store a canary beforehand in the unused space, and check afterwards that it hasn't been corrupted.  Or use the MPU, like efence does.  Lots of ways to detect out of bounds access.